# Изменение данных пользователей в Django

Tags: python, django, валидация

Пытаюсь изменить данные пользователей, но не получается. Пишет, что неверное значение, что делать?

views.py:

```py
@login_required
def сhange_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CustomUserChangeForm()
        return render(request, 'profiles/change.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return redirect('profile')
```

models.py:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=124, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number']

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py:

```py
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number')
```

```
change.html

Страница для изменений данных!

    {{ error }}

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label for="title">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ user.email }}">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="title">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ user.first_name }}">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="title">Фамилия</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{ user.last_name }}">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="title">Номер телефона</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="{{ user.phone_number }}">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Стек ошибки от django

```
ValueError at /profile/сhange/
The CustomUser could not be created because the data didn't validate.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/%D1%81hange/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The CustomUser could not be created because the data didn't validate.
Exception Location: C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py, line 458, in save
Python Executable:  C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Timofey\\patterson-project',
 'C:\\Timofey\\patterson-project',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2021.2.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Users\\evgen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\evgen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\evgen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\evgen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Timofey\\patterson-project\\venv',
 'C:\\Timofey\\patterson-project\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2021.2.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Sat, 26 Feb 2022 10:42:17 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
Local vars
C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py, line 21, in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Timofey\patterson-project\profiles\views.py, line 18, in сhange_profile
        form.save() …
Local vars
C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py, line 458, in save
            raise ValueError(
```

[image: error]

Comment: Код и стек ошибок в вопросе должны быть в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотами. Иначе вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: Так нужно изменить?

Comment: да, теперь все в порядке. спасибо за понимание

Comment: у вас в ошибке прямо написано, что не проходит валидация. вероятно потому, что вы проверяете на наличие метода GET, а используете метод POST. Попробуйте в change.html изменить `<form method="POST">`  на `<form method="GET">`

Comment: Нет, я сработало, такая же ошибка

Comment: Я уже третий час думаю, ничего не получается. Возможно у меня не валидная форма, так как я делал проверку на это. Модель пользователя я делал с помощью AbstractBaseUser возможно это из-за этого, я не знаю. Я устал и мне печально